# How to use prometheusScrap with Datadog to ingest custom metrics

Tags: datadog

I'm trying to configure my datadog agent to do prometheus checks with the following in my values.yaml file:

```
  prometheusScrape:
    enabled: true
    serviceEndpoints: true
    additionalConfigs:
      -
        configurations:
          - collect_histogram_buckets: true
```

but I end up getting the following error when checking the status of the agent:

```
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/opt/datadog-agent/embedded/lib/python3.8/site-packages/datadog_checks/base/checks/base.py", line 1091, in run
          initialization()
        File "/opt/datadog-agent/embedded/lib/python3.8/site-packages/datadog_checks/base/checks/openmetrics/v2/base.py", line 83, in configure_scrapers
          scrapers[endpoint] = self.create_scraper(config)
        File "/opt/datadog-agent/embedded/lib/python3.8/site-packages/datadog_checks/base/checks/openmetrics/v2/base.py", line 90, in create_scraper
          return OpenMetricsScraper(self, self.get_config_with_defaults(config))
        File "/opt/datadog-agent/embedded/lib/python3.8/site-packages/datadog_checks/base/checks/openmetrics/v2/scraper.py", line 64, in __init__
          self.metric_transformer = MetricTransformer(self.check, config)
        File "/opt/datadog-agent/embedded/lib/python3.8/site-packages/datadog_checks/base/checks/openmetrics/v2/transform.py", line 50, in __init__
          self.metric_patterns.append((re.compile(raw_metric_name), config))
        File "/opt/datadog-agent/embedded/lib/python3.8/re.py", line 252, in compile
          return _compile(pattern, flags)
        File "/opt/datadog-agent/embedded/lib/python3.8/re.py", line 304, in _compile
          p = sre_compile.compile(pattern, flags)
        File "/opt/datadog-agent/embedded/lib/python3.8/sre_compile.py", line 764, in compile
          p = sre_parse.parse(p, flags)
        File "/opt/datadog-agent/embedded/lib/python3.8/sre_parse.py", line 948, in parse
          p = _parse_sub(source, state, flags & SRE_FLAG_VERBOSE, 0)
        File "/opt/datadog-agent/embedded/lib/python3.8/sre_parse.py", line 443, in _parse_sub
          itemsappend(_parse(source, state, verbose, nested + 1,
        File "/opt/datadog-agent/embedded/lib/python3.8/sre_parse.py", line 668, in _parse
          raise source.error("nothing to repeat",
      re.error: nothing to repeat at position 0
```

I'm basing my config on the example from the [helm chart](https://github.com/DataDog/helm-charts/blob/datadog-3.1.3/charts/datadog/values.yaml#L654).

I've also added an ADP 2 annotation to my pod (shown below from `kubectl describe pod`):

```
Annotations:      ad.datadoghq.com/rpc-node-proxy.checks:
                    {
                                    "openmetrics": {
                                      "instances": [
                                        {
                                          "openmetrics_endpoint": "http://%%host%%:3000/metrics",
                                          "namespace": "rpc-node-proxy",
                                          "collect_histogram_buckets": true,
                                          "metrics": ["*"]
                                        }
                                      ]
                                     }
                                 }
                  kubernetes.io/psp: eks.privileged
                  prometheus.io/scrape: true
```

Viewing the logs of my agent I see the following:

```
2022-10-05 15:02:53 UTC | CORE | INFO | (pkg/collector/python/datadog_agent.go:127 in LogMessage) | openmetrics:1067ca789343c469 | (base.py:60) | Scraping OpenMetrics endpoint: http://192.168.180.78:3000/metrics
2022-10-05 15:03:00 UTC | CORE | ERROR | (pkg/collector/worker/check_logger.go:69 in Error) | check:openmetrics | Error running check: [{"message": "nothing to repeat at position 0", "traceback": "Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File \"/opt/datadog-agent/embedded/lib/python3.8/site-packages/datadog_checks/base/checks/base.py\", line 1091, in run\n    initialization()\n  File \"/opt/datadog-agent/embedded/lib/python3.8/site-packages/datadog_checks/base/checks/openmetrics/v2/base.py\", line 83, in configure_scrapers\n    scrapers[endpoint] = self.create_scraper(config)\n  File \"/opt/datadog-agent/embedded/lib/python3.8/site-packages/datadog_checks/base/checks/openmetrics/v2/base.py\", line 90, in create_scraper\n    return OpenMetricsScraper(self, self.get_config_with_defaults(config))\n  File \"/opt/datadog-agent/embedded/lib/python3.8/site-packages/datadog_checks/base/checks/openmetrics/v2/scraper.py\", line 64, in __init__\n    self.metric_transformer = MetricTransformer(self.check, config)\n  File \"/opt/datadog-agent/embedded/lib/python3.8/site-packages/datadog_checks/base/checks/openmetrics/v2/transform.py\", line 50, in __init__\n    self.metric_patterns.append((re.compile(raw_metric_name), config))\n  File \"/opt/datadog-agent/embedded/lib/python3.8/re.py\", line 252, in compile\n    return _compile(pattern, flags)\n  File \"/opt/datadog-agent/embedded/lib/python3.8/re.py\", line 304, in _compile\n    p = sre_compile.compile(pattern, flags)\n  File \"/opt/datadog-agent/embedded/lib/python3.8/sre_compile.py\", line 764, in compile\n    p = sre_parse.parse(p, flags)\n  File \"/opt/datadog-agent/embedded/lib/python3.8/sre_parse.py\", line 948, in parse\n    p = _parse_sub(source, state, flags & SRE_FLAG_VERBOSE, 0)\n  File \"/opt/datadog-agent/embedded/lib/python3.8/sre_parse.py\", line 443, in _parse_sub\n    itemsappend(_parse(source, state, verbose, nested + 1,\n  File \"/opt/datadog-agent/embedded/lib/python3.8/sre_parse.py\", line 668, in _parse\n    raise source.error(\"nothing to repeat\",\nre.error: nothing to repeat at position 0\n"}]
2022-10-05 15:03:02 UTC | CORE | INFO | (pkg/serializer/serializer.go:401 in sendMetadata) | Sent metadata payload, size (raw/compressed): 3635/1146 bytes.
2022-10-05 15:03:03 UTC | CORE | INFO | (pkg/serializer/serializer.go:425 in SendProcessesMetadata) | Sent processes metadata payload, size: 1476 bytes.
```

and I've verified that http://192.168.180.78:3000/metrics is emitting metrics by exec-ing into the pod, installing curl and executing `curl http://192.168.180.78:3000/metrics` which outputted many metrics like the following:

```
rpc_request_duration_ms_bucket{le="5",nodeName="optimism-alchemy",nodeUrl="https://opt-goerli.g.alchemy.com./v2/rlEHpvxAL--b_Oa",network="optimism-goerli",rpcMethod="eth_getTransactionReceipt",weight="1",app="rpc-node-proxy"} 0
rpc_request_duration_ms_bucket{le="10",nodeName="optimism-alchemy",nodeUrl="https://opt-goerli.g.alchemy.com./v2/rlEHpvxAL--b_Oa",network="optimism-goerli",rpcMethod="eth_getTransactionReceipt",weight="1",app="rpc-node-proxy"} 0
rpc_request_duration_ms_bucket{le="+Inf",nodeName="optimism-alchemy",nodeUrl="https://opt-goerli.g.alchemy.com./v2/rlEHpvxAL--b_Oa",network="optimism-goerli",rpcMethod="eth_getTransactionReceipt",weight="1",app="rpc-node-proxy"} 9
rpc_request_duration_ms_sum{nodeName="optimism-alchemy",nodeUrl="https://opt-goerli.g.alchemy.com./v2/rlEHpvxAL--b_Oa",network="optimism-goerli",rpcMethod="eth_getTransactionReceipt",weight="1",app="rpc-node-proxy"} 916
```

What does this datadog agent error mean and how can I debug it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ah, looks like `"metrics": ["*"]` needs to be `"metrics": [".*"]`